# Data Json image cant displayed at view laravel 5.8

Tags: json, laravel

i have data Json like this :

```
"id" => 126
"user_id" => 2
"alat_id" => 7
"pertanyaan" => "{"question1":"Kondisi, kebersihan, pelumasan bearing","answer1":"baik","image":"FOTO.jpeg"} ◀"
"catatan" => "hiyahiya"
"status" => "3 Bulanan"
"deleted_at" => null
"created_at" => "2019-04-16 06:21:50"
"updated_at" => "2019-04-16 06:21:50"
```

on json data "pertanyaan" i have image named FOTO.jpeg .

i have a function to showing data like this and its not have error :

```
             <p> Laporan      : {{ $pemeliharaan->status }} </p> 
             <p> Tanggal      : {{ $pemeliharaan->created_at }} </p> 
             <p> Jenis Alat   : {{ $pemeliharaan->alat->nama_alat }} </p> 
             <p> User         : {{ $pemeliharaan->user->name }} </p>  
             <p> Catatan      : {{ $pemeliharaan->catatan}} </p>
```

and i have view to showing this :

```
 <td><img src="{{ public_path('images/{{$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'] }}')}}"></td>
```

but having error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'image' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /var/www/html/new/resources/views/users/question/view_question2.blade.php)
```

can someone correct my error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues in your code.

1. There is no need to open {{}} inside another {{}}.

```php
 <td><img src="{{ public_path('images/'.$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'])}}"></td>
```

This should fix your syntax error.

2. However there's another issue, public_path() will return an absolute path with respect to your system, so the generated url would look something like '/var/www/html/new/public/some_image.png'

The correct code would look like:

```php
 <td><img src="{{ url('images/'.$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'])}}"></td>
```

This should return a url like 127.0.0.1:8000/images/some_image.png

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 <td><img src="{{ public_path('images/'.{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'] }} ) }}"></td>
```

You are not concatenating string.